# Pandas Concat 500 CSV Files Within S3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

I do have around 500 `CSV` file within `S3 Bucket`

> Note: Each file size is around 1 GB, Around ~6m of lines.

What am trying to do is to concatenate all those CSV files into a single file.

I'm trying to speed up the Process but am not sure what else i can do in such case!

Below is my code:

```py
import trio
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial

AWS_ID = 'Hidden'
AWS_SECRET = 'Hidden'
Bucket_Name = 'Hidden'

limiter = trio.CapacityLimiter(10)


async def read_object(bucket, object_csv, sender):
    async with limiter, sender:
        print(f'Reading {object_csv}')

        test = bucket.Object(object_csv)
        test = test.get()['Body']
        data = await trio.to_thread.run_sync(partial(pd.read_csv, test, header=None))
        await sender.send(data)


async def main():
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nurse:
        s3 = boto3.resource(
            service_name='s3',
            aws_access_key_id=AWS_ID,
            aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET,
        )
        bucket = s3.Bucket(Bucket_Name)
        allfiles = [i.key for i in bucket.objects.all()]
        sender, receiver = trio.open_memory_channel(0)
        nurse.start_soon(rec, receiver)
        async with sender:
            for f in allfiles:
                nurse.start_soon(read_object, bucket, f, sender.clone())


async def rec(receiver):
    alldf = []
    async with receiver:
        async for df in receiver:
            alldf.append(df)
    final = pd.concat(alldf, ignore_index=True)
    print(final)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        trio.run(main)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit('Job Cancelled!')
```

The part which is taking time:

```
data = await trio.to_thread.run_sync(partial(pd.read_csv, test, header=None))
```

For a single file it's taking about 2 minutes. Also I'm running the operation under threads! so it's taking a lot!

> Update: New Code is Below:

```py
limiter = trio.CapacityLimiter(10)


async def read_object(bucket, object_csv, sender):
    async with limiter, sender:
        print(f'Reading {object_csv}')

        test = bucket.Object(object_csv)
        test = test.get()['Body']
        data = await trio.to_thread.run_sync(test.read)
        await sender.send(data)
        print(f'Done Reading {object_csv}')


async def main():
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nurse:
        s3 = boto3.resource(
            service_name='s3',
            aws_access_key_id=AWS_ID,
            aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET,
        )
        bucket = s3.Bucket(Bucket_Name)
        sender, receiver = trio.open_memory_channel(0)
        nurse.start_soon(rec, receiver)
        async with sender:
            for csv in bucket.objects.all():
                nurse.start_soon(read_object, bucket, csv.key, sender.clone())


async def rec(receiver):
    async with receiver, await trio.open_file('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
        count = 0
        async for df in receiver:
            count += 1
            await f.write(df)
            await f.write(b"\n")
            print(f'Collected {count}', flush=True, end='\r')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        trio.run(main)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit('Job Cancelled!')
```

Based on that code, is it possible to speed up the process more than that ?

Comment: How much time is it taking to run at the moment? Which part is taking longest time?

Comment: `pd.concat(alldf...)` Given that you have a step where you have every dataframe in memory at the same time, you're going to need around 1500 GB of memory. (Rule of thumb is that loading a CSV file in Pandas takes the 3x the memory of the file's size.)

Comment: @NickODell what's your recommendation for such case ?

Comment: Personally, I'd think about whether you need Pandas at all. For example, if the fields match up between every file, you could just throw away the first line of each file and write the remainder to the output file. It's always faster to avoid parsing the CSV if that's possible. If they don't match up... that's still possible, but it's more complicated.

Comment: @NickODell good hint. Thank you. i updated my Question with a new code based on your suggestion. Do you think that i can speed up the process more than the way i do currently ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Can you post a benchmark, in terms of the speed of the new code in MB/s? What's the fastest you can read and write S3 files on your current connection?